# Visual Studio / C++ -- How to prevent it from phoning home?

Tags: visual-studio

I am sorry if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find it anywhere, so that is why I am making a post here.

Recently I have built a portable executable via Visual Studio Community 2022, since it's just a matter of convenience. I have noticed something, though.
If I run my completely clean executable through VirusTotal, I can see that it contacts 4 IP addresses, no matter what code is in the executable or not. *Every single time, it's the same 4 IP addresses.* A screenshot is provided below.
[image: Always the 4 contacted IPs...]

Obviously, I searched online and through reddit posts, wondering if someone had the same problem, and was advised through other comments to go into Privacy, and turn off optional **Visual Studio Experience Improvement Program**, via Help > Privacy.

I did this, and it did not help. These 4 IP addresses are still contacted.

So, I ask you all. Is there a way for my program to stop this? Is this a false flag? Do I have to use another compiler like g++ or clang++, or have to stop using Visual Studio altogether? I look forward to your responses.

Comment: Block the application from accessing the internet.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dxc0NSuCLj8

Comment: Are you saying that even if you compile a simple "Hello World" program, the resulting executable tries to connect to those IP-addresses?

Comment: Digicert oscp server? Are you using tls? https://knowledge.digicert.com/alerts/new-dedicated-ip-addresses.html

Comment: "f I run my through VirusTotal"... Can you explain exactly what you're doing and give a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @heapunderrun yes, that's correct, although from my testing it contacted 3, not 4; I don't know what that's about.
But yes, building a simple "hello world" program in C++ VS 2022 Community Edition, Building x64 Release with C++ Latest Version, and all other settings default, it contacts IP addresses.
You can see this here: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/43c74991f34049ba1586071bd66a5520980e207d2f6fab801ae022296798b6ed/behavior